# Are there any other words that are spelled with "a" but pronounced with /e/ like many, any?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography

Are there any other words that are spelled with "a" but pronounced with the **standard phoneme** /e/ in **Received Pronunciation** like *many*, *any*?

**Exceptions**: derivatives of *any* (*anything*, *anyone*, *anytime*, etc.); other regional/dialectal mergers (such as the Mary-marry-merry merger); /eər/ as in *Mary*.

Comment: There are care/carry and fare. I guess the vowel e or y changes the sound.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany care is pronounced /keər/ which I already excluded. carry is pronounced /kæri/ in Received Pronunciation.

Comment: @Sven Yargs separate is pronounced with two schwas, not "short "e" sound", which is totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

Some people (including me) have /ɛ/ in *catch* (this is listed as the second pronunciation by [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catch)) although for me the vowel in this word is more variable than the one in *many* and *any* (I might say /kætʃ/, while I would never say /æni/).

The past tense of *eat,* which is standardly spelled "ate," may be pronounced /ɛt/ (see this map from the *[Cambridge Online Survey of World Englishes](http://www.tekstlab.uio.no/cambridge_survey/maps/97)*). This is only present in the accents of certain regions; I think it is more common in the UK than in North America.

Some people pronounce [*pall-mall*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pall-mall) as /pɛlmɛl/ ([American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=pall-mall)) although alternate spellings that fit this pronunciation better do exist, such as "paille-maille" and "pell-mell."

Place names often have unintuitive spellings; one place name spelled with "a" but pronounced with /ɛ/ is the River Thames /tɛmz/ ([Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/thames)).

Loanwords also are often spelled according to different patterns. The German word *Doppelgänger* is often used in English with the spelling *[doppelganger](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Doppelganger)*; even when the umlaut on the *a* is dropped, the vowel may still be pronounced as /ɛ/.

Comment: Just found marshmallow ("marshmellow").